# Should I turn the text on my poster to outlines before I print?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, print-design

What would be the best practice for printing text based work from Illustrator, such as a poster? This is aimed at the final print quality of my workk.

I am creating an advertisement which will be about A4 size to go into a newspaper. Would it be best to Create Outline all the text in the advert before I send the files off to be printed or will it not make much of a difference in terms of quality?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Customarily, you'd send a PDF/X-1a file with fonts embedded by simply saving that format (with crops and bleed), therefore outlining type would actually *not always* be a good thing. PDF/X-1a is often preferred because it is a self-contained format with fonts embedded and artwork flattened. This ensures the most accurate preproduction.

If you are sending a .eps or .ai file, then outlining type is the best practice.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I am sending a PDF so I will take this into consideration.